# How to set two root endpoints in one file Restful API with node.js & EXPRESS

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, api, express

I have root endpoint who work when users enter the url like this:

http://localhost:8000/?date=2019-10-20&station=41027&daysForward=3

I want to create second root endpoint in the same file with different query but that did not work.

My code:

```
// Create express app
var express = require("express")
var app = express()
var mysql = require('mysql')
var express = require("express")
var cors = require('cors')

app.use(cors())

// Server port
var HTTP_PORT = 8000

// Start server
app.listen(HTTP_PORT, () => {
    console.log("Server running on port %PORT%".replace("%PORT%",HTTP_PORT))
});

var con = mysql.createConnection({
  host: "192.168.1.1",
  port: "3456",
  user: "user",
  password: "pass"
});

var con2 = mysql.createConnection({
  host: "192.168.1.1",
  port: "3456",
  user: "user",
  password: "pass"
});

let aladinModel= '';
let aladinModelStations = '';

app.route('/')
.get(function(req, res) {
  // omitted
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  const date = req.query.date;
  const station = req.query.station;
  const daysForward = req.query.daysForward;
  try {
    const query = `CALL aladin_surfex.Get_mod_cell_values_meteogram('${date}', ${station}, ${daysForward})`;
    con.query(query, function (err, result, fields) {
      if (err) throw err;
      aladinModel = result;
    });
    res.json({aladinModel})
  } catch(error){
    console.log("Error query database!!!");
  } 
});

app.route('/stations')
.get(function(req, res) {
  // omitted
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  try {
    const query2 = `SELECT Station,Ime FROM stations_cells`;
    con2.query2(query2, function (err, result2, fields) {
      if (err) throw err;
      aladinModelStations = result2;
    });
    res.json({aladinModelStations})
  } catch(error){
    console.log("Error query database!!!");

  } 
});

app.use(function(req, res){
    res.status(404);
});
```

I guess this is not the right way to route pages but I hope someone can explain to me with an example how I could fix the code - so when a user enters:

```
http://localhost:3000/stations
```

the data should be loaded.

I see this error when I try to open this link.

```
[nodemon] starting `node server.js localhost:8000`
Server running on port 8000
Error query database!!!
```

This query

```
SELECT station, ime 
FROM stations_cells
```

on the second root point is fine. I try to `SELECT` with HeidiSQL and database return the data values ?

[image: **SELECT station,ime FROM stations_cells**]

Where is the problem for the second root point ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That might not be the case, but here's the suggestion (which doesn't fit in comment section)

```
app.route('/')
  .get(function(req, res) {
    // omitted
  });

app.route('/stations')
  .get(function(req, res) {
    // omitted
  });
```

Comment: I update the question.
The second query crash the node.js server when I put in URL localhost:8000/stations

Comment: I update again the question. With your code the second query looks fine but node.js say: Error query database!!!